# php get ID from another page

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 pages...

```
   Page1 (transaction table page)
```

The first page is a Transaction Table with  by $_GET to show all data from the user.
then, i  create a  $_POST, when clicked go to the "Refund page".

```
   Page1 (Refund page)
```

In this page i've got a functions to give back the money to the user, but is not complete, because i dont have the Transaction ID that is required to ask a refund...

My question is... How can i get an ID from another page?...

Comment: The **code** that you have is relevant here and yet not shown. Edit your question to add it to give context to what you're trying to do.

Comment: but my question is not show u the code... is ask u how can i GET the ID from the PAGE 1 to the PAGE 2

Comment: Example... To show the table i used if($_GET['id']  with <a href='". $id."'>

Comment: but in another page i wanna show that ID in the new page...

Comment: You despertately need a primer on basic PHP, plus you should probably avoid low-level coding if you're still not sure how to organize an application. Trying something like [Laravel](http://laravel.com) will be a lot more rewarding because it will direct you towards useful solution patterns.

Comment: i fixe it... just put              <a href='asp/class/includes/public_refund.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' id='cancelOrder'>Cancel</a>

And try to send to the refund page... Thank your for your help, for something so easy... ;D

Comment: It would have helped if you explained what `$row` was and where it came from. Your question leaves a lot of that as guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Send the data via POST, in hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="TRXXX" />
```

Comment: how can i send the ID from the table via form??...How possible is that?
like that?                  <input type='submit' name='". $transaction_ID . "' id='cancelOrder' value='Cancel' />

Comment: if is like that how can i open in another page??... like.. if($_POST['WHAT?']